# Is there a thing that reads out loud Japanese and highlights each syllable?

Tags: discussion, learning

I have a weird way of learning things. In order to learn Japanese, I need a program - an app or website or something - that reads Japanese out loud and for each syllable that is read, it lights up the symbol or character corresponding to that sound/syllable. Is there anything like that?

Comment: Unfortunately this is fundamentally impossible. Many kanji contain more than one 'syllable' in their pronunciation. I guess it could work if everything was in kana but I don't know of any such software.